# react-date-range as read only calendar

Tags: reactjs, date, react-date-range

I'm looking for a way to use `react-date-range` in display only mode:

- no inputs
- no calendar selection
- no change event

The goal is to be able to show ranges on the calendar without allowing changes to it. (Some users have sets the ranges, some users can only view them)

So far I've managed to:

- disable the inputs
- hide the preview on hover
- not respond to selection

```
<DateRange
        ranges={[state.selection1, state.selection2, state.selection3]}
        editableDateInputs={false}
        showPreview={false}
        onChange={()=>{}}
        rangeColors={["#FFB800", "#B8FF00", "#B800FF"]}
      />
```

Then I can do some css hacking:

```
.rdrDateDisplayWrapper {
   display: none; 
}
// etc
```

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will be better off using a separate component rather than trying to make a workaround with `react-date-range`.

You should be good using the new `react-lightweight-calendar` which is feature rich and smaller in size compared to the older `react-calendar` component. Both of which were designed for the use case you described.